# Плавное изменение градиента

Tags: css3

Подскажите, как плавно изменить градиент с помощью CSS3?
Вот код:

```css
#change:hover {
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ccc, green);
}
#change {
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #ccc;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777, green); /* для webkit-браузеров */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-linear-gradient 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id=change>
  Буквы<br>
  на градиентном<br>
  фоне
</div>
```

Comment: Ребят, неужели больше нет идей?((

Comment: Вон ответ который я прокомментировал. Он отличный. Как пример 
http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/ZOOPap

Answer (score 4):

Можно следующим образом:

```
.btn-orange {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffa435, #e6561b, #c5440f);
  height: 40px;
  background-size: 1px 80px;
}
.btn-orange:hover {
  background-position: 40px;
}
```

Получается, фон сдвигается, но за счёт плавности градиента создаётся эффект плавности. Если градиент ступенчатый - будет заметно скольжение фона.

Comment: Обалденное решение, взял себе на заметку, спасибо. PS. надо только добавить настройку самой анимации `transition: background .3s;` http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/ZOOPap

Answer (score 2):

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #008040 0%,  #00ff40 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #008040 0%, #00ff40 100%);
```

Вот [тут подробнее](http://htmlbook.ru/css/-webkit-linear-gradient) об этом

Comment: Я про другое. Как создавать градиенты я знаю. Мне нужно, чтобы при наведении на элемент он плавно изменялся. Т.е. нужно что-то в этом участке кода изменить: 

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-linear-gradient 2s;

Answer (score 1):

По наводке от @j-tap.
Проверено в firefox и chromium.

```css
#change:hover {
   background-position:0 0;
}
#change {
   border-top: 1px solid silver;
   background-color: #555;
   color: #ccc;
   background: linear-gradient(#ccc, #585, green);
   background-size: 100% 140%;
   background-position:0 100%;
   transition: background 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id=change>
  Буквы<br>
  на градиентном<br>
  фоне
</div>
```